# How to drop redundant column in data.frame that introduced by `bind_rows`?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frame within the list which has the different column, I intend to combine them into one list of data.frame, and I used the existing solution in `SO`. Yes, `dplyr` function works pretty well, but `bind_rows` introduce extra column which is needed for splitting. However, I want to continue the pipeline after splitting single data.frame, to drop the redundant column in each data.frame simultaneously. I tried of using `select` to cancel out the column, but it doesn't work. Is that possible to continue my pipeline to drop the column instead of using another `lapply` to do this? How can I make this happen? Any idea?

Here is the data.frame list that I need to merge, then split it:

```
DF <- list(
    hue = data.frame( begin=seq(1, by=6, len=10), end=seq(4, by=6, len=10), val=sample(30, 10)),
    ack = data.frame( begin=seq(3, by=9, len=8), end=seq(6, by=9, len=8), val=sample(45, 8)),
    ken = data.frame( begin=seq(6, by=8, len=6), end=seq(11, by=8, len=6), val=sample(52, 6))
)

MF <- list(
    hue = data.frame( begin=seq(11, by=6, len=7), end=seq(14, by=6, len=7), 
                      val=sample(30, 7), cmb.val=sample(24, 7)),
    ack = data.frame( begin=seq(13, by=9, len=5), end=seq(6, by=9, len=5), 
                      val=sample(45, 5), cmb.val=sample(18, 5)),
    ken = data.frame( begin=seq(16, by=8, len=6), end=seq(21, by=8, len=6), 
                      val=sample(52, 6), cmb.val=sample(20, 6))
)
```

Here is my solution to merge and split operation:

```
res <- bind_rows(DF, MF, .id = "GRP") %>% 
    mutate(cmb.val = ifelse(is.na(cmb.val),0,cmb.val)) %>%
    split(.$GRP)
```

I am curious about the possibility of continuing the above pipeline and drop the redundant column `GRP` in each data.frame. Perhaps my attempt won't be feasible, but try this option instead of using `lapply` approach in the new line.

In my desired output, `GRP` column should not be included in each data.frame.

Can anyone give me a possible idea to do this? Is that possible to continue above pipeline for dropping extra column `GRP` ? Thanks in advance

Comment: just add `%>% lapply(select, -GRP)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
bind_rows(DF, MF, .id = "GRP") %>% 
        mutate(cmb.val = ifelse(is.na(cmb.val),0,cmb.val)) %>%
        split(.$GRP) %>%
        map(~.[setdiff(names(.), "GRP")])
        #or with `select`
        #map(~select(., -one_of("GRP")))
```

Comment: Dear akrun, Thanks for your brilliant idea. Instead of using `purrr`, could we use `dplyr` function? In this case, no need to depend another package. Thank you

Comment: @Dan It comes along with `tidyverse` package list.   So, if you install tidyverse, you install all of those packages

Comment: @Dan As I mentioned in the comments, you can check [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse)

Comment: Dear akrun, Yes, using `tidyverse` make package installation easier. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `lapply()` with `select()` as follows:

```
bind_rows(DF, MF, .id = "GRP") %>% 
    mutate(cmb.val = ifelse(is.na(cmb.val), 0, cmb.val)) %>%
    split(.$GRP) %>%
    lapply(select, -GRP)
```